# Express.js - is there a way to find out the router stack that express uses to resolve a request?

Tags: express

Is there a way to find out the stack of routes that express uses to resolve a request to a particular route handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time but found it.

Every express app uses an internal `app._router`.

You can access the router stack with `app._router.stack`

PS - Anything with an `_` is meant for private use.